# LiveSearchGridPanel not accessible from Sencha Architect 3

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

As useful as Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel may be, I don't find a way to use it from Sencha Architect 3.
Anybody knows how I can use it from Architect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ext.ux.* portions of the ExtJS frameworks are "unofficial"-ish, and therefore aren't included in Architect by default.

You could, however, load it in to architect with a bit of work by wrapping it in a user extension package.

http://www.sencha.com/blog/building-a-user-extension-and-integrating-it-into-sencha-architect-3-part-2/

Note that sometimes you may need to make an adjustment here or there to the code so that it'll run in Architect's canvas (for example, a class that expects certain parameters immediately upon creation may need to be adjusted to live inside of Architect's canvas because it'll get created without those parameters unless you provide defaults, etc)...

See also this post on the Sencha forums from about a year ago now for an alternative solution:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?259804-Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel-for-architect

Comment: I've tried LiveSearchGridPanel outside Sencha Architect and it is too slow. I think it is better to invoke browser find (ctrl+F) and look for the result.